# Area of fourth quadrant in unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

In an exercise, I tried to integrate a function over the area for the fourth quadrant of the unit circle $(3\pi/2 \rightarrow 2\pi)$. I am pretty confused about the answer.

I tried translating the original integral to polar coordinates as follows
$$
\iint_D xy~dxdy = \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r\cos\theta\sin\theta~drd\theta
$$
but I get twice the area that I'm supposed to get ($-1/4$ instead of $-1/8$). I can't find anything that looks off with my integral. Am I doing this wrong, and what?

Also... wouldn't you rather have a positive area?

Comment: The function is $f(x,y)=xy$ in the domain $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have \begin{align*}\int\limits_{\theta=1.5\pi}^{2\pi}\ \int\limits_{r=0}^{1}r\cos\theta\sin\theta\text{d}r\text{d}\theta&=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{1.5\pi}^{2\pi}\sin(2\theta)\text{d}\theta\int\limits_{0}^{1}r\text{d}r \\&=-\frac{1}{8}\Big.\cos(2\theta)\Big\vert_{1.5\pi}^{2\pi}\cdot \Big.r^2\Big\vert_{0}^{1}=-\frac{1}{4}\end{align*}

Comment: hmm... [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B3pi%2F2%7D%5E%7B2pi%7D+(++%5Cint_0%5E1+(r*cos+(theta)+sin(theta)+)+dr)d%5Ctheta) solves it to $\frac{-1}{4}$. I solved it using the variable substitution $u = \sin(x) \Leftrightarrow d\theta = \frac{du}{\cos\theta}$

Comment: Oh! I think [this site](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/08/09/the-perplexing-integral-of-sin-xcos-x-sunday-puzzle/) explains why we get different results. I am not sure which one yields the correct area though...

Comment: The results are not different, I had a mistake in calculation... Why do you think it should be - 1/8?

Comment: The suggested answer to the exercise is $-1/8$. But okay interesting. The site I linked, explains that$-\cos^2(\theta)/2$, $-\cos(2\theta)/4$ and $\sin^2(\theta)/2$ are all primitives to the function, while your method gives: $-\frac{1}{4}\cos(2\theta) = -\frac{1}{4}(2\cos^2(\theta) - 1) = -\cos^2(\theta)/2 + 1/4$ and my solution $\sin^2(\theta)/2 = -\frac{1}{2}(2\cos^2(\theta) - 1)  = -\cos^2(\theta)/2 + 1/2$

Comment: I think the coefficient should be $-1/4$ from $1/2(-\cos(2\theta)/2)$. I get the result $-1/2$ for $-(\cos(4\pi) - \cos(3\pi))$, which holds true for the differing constants.

Comment: Don't forget the integral on $r$ which gives 1/2.

Comment: Ok, yes this is completely true! The constant I was talking about doesn't matter of course when integrating between to points on the same primitive function. The answer is $-1/4$ no matter the method :) suggested answer was wrong for once

Comment: I just realized... $xy$ in polar coordinates results in $r²\cos\theta\sin\theta$ right? that would yield $-1/8$ instead.